# Get Instances by public IPV4 ip

Tags: python, boto3

The documentation is not clear whether I can filter/search for instances by their public ip address. Is there a way to do this in the SDK API? The brute force solution for me to do is get all instances then filter with the list of ip_addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Use the `ip-address` filter for the [`describe_instances()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) call, like this to filter by a given List of IPv4 addresses:

```
import boto3
ec2_conn = boto3.client('ec2')
ec2_conn.describe_instances(
  Filters=[{'Name': 'ip-address', 'Values': ['1.2.3.4', '5.6.7.8']}])
```